# Finding Roots of a Polynomial in a Given Range

Tags: polynomials, matlab, mathematica

I want to be able to analyze complicated polynomials (degree $6,7$ etc.) and find out if they have roots in a given range. How do I proceed to do this using Mathematica, Matlab, or analytically(if possible at all)?

Also, how do I prove (or at least convince myself), or disprove if a large polynomial has a unique positive root?

I'm beginning to learn Matlab and Mathematica so I would really appreciate it if you can provide me with a source(s) to learn these things. Thank you!

Comment: Are you interested only in real roots?

Comment: Mostly, yes. I want to explore the behavior of a given polynomial. Roots, y-intercept, behavior as x goes to infinity etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with Descartes' rule of signs?  With [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)?  If you just want to do it programmatically, I'm sure the languages you mention can find the roots of those polynomials numerically for you.

Comment: You could use [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to count and isolate real roots. Another method is using [Vincent's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation#Vincent's_and_related_theorems).

Comment: I knew about Descartes' rule of signs but I didn't know about Sturm's theorem and Vincent's theorem. Thank you so much for this information. I just read about them and unfortunately I don't think they will be of much help, due to the complexity of polynomials I am dealing with. The coefficients of my polynomials are not real numbers. They are (positive) parameters, which can take several values. So finding roots analytically is extremely difficult. I hope someone will be able to help with Matlab and Mathematica.

Comment: You can still compute Sturm sequences for your parametric polynomials. They will just be parametric themselves.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try this! It's going to be a very long calculation but I'll enjoy doing this. Once again, thanks so much!!